# How to properly create assets and design a screen for Android?

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android development, and this time, not a programming question on SO, but rather a question about image design on Android.

I'm a bit lost in the densities of the devices.
The goal of my application is to support as much as possible devices.

Now, I own a Nexus 5 device, of which I know that it's a `xxhdpi` screen with a resolution of `1920 x 1080`.
Since it's an `xxhdpi` device, the scaling factor is 3, so for simplicity, I divide it by 3 which given me the following resolution on `mdpi` and on `mdpi` 1px is equal to 1dp.
Therefore, my Android device is `360 x 640dp`.

So, I create a new document in InkScape or Illustrator, whatever you want and create my design based on that particular resolution.

Now, I know that on my device the navigation bar is 48dp and the and the status bar is 25dp, which gives me a content area of `360 x 567 dp`.

I've found the information about the screens here: http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

What I see on this page is that other devices have another status bar height, another action bar height and that the DP's doesn't equal accross various devices.

So, the question is, how can I design a screen of which I'm sure that it will support all the available screens on the market?

Kind regards

Comment: You first line, must be raising eyebrows of many; to close this question down.

Comment: You are asking about image design or layout design ?

Answer (score 2):

Read this carefully

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Edit :

1. Create designs for phones of hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi densities and test them on emulator.
2. Extend designs for 7" tablet and test them on emulator.
3. Move on to 10" tablets.
4. Use available online tools to test your design on a variety of screens and create specific folders using "New Size Qualifiers" as mentioned in the doc above to support those devices in which you don't see your design properly

Use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to scale your icons for different screen densities. For backgrounds, create 9-patch version of your images from the same tool. They will also be generated for different screen densities

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to care about the height of the ActionBar's height and all. If you put the images of multiple resolution in the respective drawable folders that's enough. e.g. Same image with different resolutions has to be put in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc. That's all you need to do. Android will automatically choose the image from these folder according to device's screen resolution.

Comment: The question does not ask just about images. Its a general android design approach query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree @geekoraul that you'll need to read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) first to give you that foundation.

The take away from it is that `dp` are Android's way of defining a predictable metric to bridge across multiple device densities. The main goal is to *scale* them correctly so that it still looks consistent.

A basic workflow would be, select a target density (usually hdpi/xhdpi), create your assets, and use tools to create appropriate resources for the other densities.

Some tools are,

- [Zeplin](http://zeplin.io) - You can create you UI and all assets/resources will be generated for you (dimensions, colours, spacing, drawables etc.)
- [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) - Generates assets like icons, themes and styles